# The type or namespace IJSObjectReference could not be found

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

I just started Blazor. I am trying to invoke a javascript function from a razor partial class.

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
public partial class Counter
{
    [Inject] IJSRuntime js { get; set; }
    IJSObjectReference module;

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        module = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/Counter.js");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("displayAlert", "New message");
    }
}
```

I get the following error `The type or namespace IJSObjectReference could not be found`. There is no option to install the package in intellisense too assuming it's a missing package issue. I have searched but haven't seen anything related. I am thinking this issue has something to do with the .NET 5 release or maybe there is a package I need to install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IJSObjectReference` is only available with the .NET 5. So, creating the project with .NET 5 fixed the issue.