# Blazor load JavaScript just in Component that require <script>

Tags: javascript, blazor

I want to implement an external  (Google Maps) and it is only required in two Pages of the Blazor Server Side Application.

So my question is if it is possible to just load the  in this Pages and not directly in _Hosts File. If yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to add script tag in razor component ?

Comment: Yes that is the goal. Want to load JS to google Maps API just when required not on every page request (_Hosts):
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in .Net 5.0
[Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-javascript-isolation-and-object-references)

See [this](https://www.meziantou.net/javascript-isolation-in-blazor-components.htm)  for an introduction and code samples

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064483/the-type-or-namespace-ijsobjectreference-could-not-be-found)